# License Management App not activating licenses

Tags: managed-package, licenses, lma

I've had a couple of instances recently where marking a license as 'Active' in the LMA and clearing out the expiry date does not seem to actually take effect within the user's org. In our LMA org, the license stays listed as Active with no expiry date, but when I look at the subscriber details in the Subscribers tab, they are still listed as being on trial.

Only after setting the expiration date to an actual date, then clearing it again does the subscriber license status change to active. I would then confirm with the user that they have access to the app, which they do.

​Anyone experiencing this?

Comment: Have you logged a case in the partner portal?

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes I have, still waiting on a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently [a known LMA bug](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YXzAAM), happening due to a workflow rule I have on new license records.